# Is there a lightweight approach in producing XML with Xerces-C++?

Tags: c++, xml, xerces-c

This application runs on an embedded platform with low processing power and memory. I want to produce huge XML from the application. Currently I am constructing DOM and serializing into XML using Xerces-C++ 3.1.1. But the DOM construction takes long time and consumes lot of memory.

I know SAX is lightweight approach of parsing XML compared to DOM. Like that is there a lightweight approach for producing XML? Ofcourse I can produce the XML by concatenating strings but I didn't choose that approach because I want to make sure I produce a well-formed XML and sanitize the texts I include in it.

Comment: You could try tinyxml, but it's horribly slow, tbh, I would use string concatenation (i.e. via a `std::ostringstream`)...

Comment: What about [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/)?

Comment: We are already written huge part of code using Xerces-C++ so trying other XML library is not an option in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is normally called streaming serialization where parts of the document are written out as they become available instead of accumulation them all and writing them out at the end (which is what the DOM approach entails).

Xerces-C++ does not currently have streaming serialization support. But it is not very difficult to emulate it using DOM. The idea is to construct a DOM document fragment when a chunk of your data is ready to be serialized, write it out using the DOMWriter API, and free it once done. When you have another chunk ready, repeat the above steps. The result is an application that uses only a fraction of the memory that would be required to create the complete document.

We use this approach in [CodeSynthesis XSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/), an XML data binding toolkit for C++, to be able to handle XML documents that are too big to fit into memory. In fact, we have written some helper classes that simplify all this and wich you can find as part of the 'streaming' example in the examples/cxx/tree/ directory (the example code is public domain so feel free to borrow it ;-)).